# How to import aar or jar file in new Bumblebee Android Studio?

Tags: import, jar, aar, android-studio-bumblebee

Android Studio 4.2 had a Reveal in Finder and you could import your aar file, but now ,in **Bumblebee** I don't know that how should **import** aar file.